# The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found

Tags: c#, generics

I have following code that I am compiling in a .NET 4.0 project

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1  
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  

        }  
    }  

    public static class Utility  
    {  
        public static IEnumerable<T> Filter1(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> predicate)  
        {  
            foreach (var item in input)  
            {  
                if (predicate(item))  
                {  
                    yield return item;  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

but getting following errors. I have System.dll already included as default in references. What I may be doing wrong?

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

Error   2   The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

Error   3   The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
public static class Utility 
{  
    public static IEnumerable<T> Filter1<T>( // Type argument on the function
       this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> predicate)  
    {
```

If you dont care if its an extension method or not, you can add a generic constrain to the class.  My guess is you want the extension method.

```
public static class Utility<T> // Type argument on class
{  
    public static IEnumerable<T> Filter1( // No longer an extension method
       IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> predicate)  
    {
```

Comment: @PaulPhillips - I actually just tried it and I dont think you can.  I removed that part of the answer.

Comment: I got it to work in linqpad, although the calling is kind of clumsy. You have to do `Utility<type>.Filter()`

Comment: Hmm interesting.  I just tried it in VS and it gave me an compilation error `Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class`.  Maybe linqpad is doing it a bit differently

Comment: Oh, my mistake.  I did not do an extension method. But you can make a static class generic.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll add that to the answer, but I'm sure the OP wants the extension method.

Answer (score 91):

You have to put the type argument on the function itself.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Filter1<T>(...)
```

Comment: A naive question, why isn't the type inference smart enough to figure it out? `IEnumerable<T> input` is passed in as an argument, so `T` is known at execution time.

Comment: My guess programmers were lazy... I saw similar patterns in the past.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 19):

You need to declare `T`, which occurs after the method name or class name. Change your method declaration to :

```
public static IEnumerable<T> 
    Filter1<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, bool> predicate)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, but solution required was slightly different. I needed to change this:

```
public static void AllItemsSatisy(this CollectionAssert collectionAssert, ICollection<T> collection, Predicate<T> predicate) 
{ ... }
```

To this:

```
public static void AllItemsSatisy<T>(this CollectionAssert collectionAssert, ICollection<T> collection, Predicate<T> predicate) 
{ ... }
```

Comment: Old Post I know but for others reading: The solution is the SAME as the accepted answer. Your code might be different but the answer is the same.  <T> is on the Method. So the type can be passed in tot he arguments and the entire method.

Comment: Just curious, did you mean to name this `AllItemsSatisfy`?

Answer (score 0):

< T > means a type of object

```
IEnumerable<yourObject>
```

Here you have more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx